# Django tests, mocking Instagram response error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, instagram-api

For past days I've been trying to write a simple test that checks if my app works. I was introduced to testing right after I got my program done so that's why I'm writing tests afterwards.

I'm using python-instagram-ext as a library and python version 3.5.2

The actual program works correctly. It simply gets the data from instagram, saves some of it to variable and prints it out.

```
def handle_instagram(self, max_tag_id, search_string=settings.SEARCH_STRING, return_count=1):
    instagram_api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
    search_string = search_string.replace('#', '')
    recent_media, next_ = instagram_api.tag_recent_media(count=5, max_tag_id=None,tag_name=search_string)

    id = recent_media[0].id
    print(id)
```

And that part works very well. But I don't want my test to request data from instagram API so I'm using mock to mock that function.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from palautebot.models import Feedback
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from palautebot.management.commands.palautebot import Command
import instagram
import datetime

class TestPalautebotTests(TestCase):
    palautebot_cmd = Command()
@mock.patch('palautebot.management.commands.palautebot.InstagramAPI')
    def test_handle_instagram(self, palautebot_instagram):
        instagram_api = palautebot_instagram.InstagramAPI.return_value
        user = instagram.models.User(1234, full_name='Test Account', username='test', profile_picture='http://pic.jpg')
        recent_media = [instagram.models.Media(
            users_in_photo= [],
            comment_count= 0,
            link= 'https://www.google.fi',
            filter= 'Crema',
            caption= instagram.models.Comment(created_at=datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 12, 9, 5, 10), user=user, id='1234', text='#nofilter Instagram test'),
            like_count= 0,
            id= '0000000000000000001_0000000001',
            comments= [],
            images= {
                'thumbnail': instagram.models.Image('http://www.google.fi', 50, 50),
                'low_resolution': instagram.models.Image('http://www.google.fi', 150, 150),
                'standard_resolution': instagram.models.Image('http://www.google.fi', 400, 400)
            },
            tags= [instagram.models.Tag('nofilter')],
            likes= [],
            user= user,
            type= 'image',
            user_has_liked= False,
            created_time= datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 12, 9, 5, 10))]

        next_ = None
        instagram_response = (recent_media, next_)
        instagram_api.tag_recent_media.return_value = instagram_response
        success_list= self.palautebot_cmd.handle_instagram(None, search_string='#nofilter')
        self.assertEqual(success_list, [True])
```

I have similar mock with facebook api and that works fine but when I try to do this mock with instagram it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/bew/bew/src/palautebot/palautebot/tests.py", line 80, in test_handle_instagram
    success_list= self.palautebot_cmd.handle_instagram(None, search_string='#helpalaute')
  File "/home/bew/bew/src/palautebot/palautebot/management/commands/palautebot.py", line 162, in handle_instagram
    tag_name=search_string
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

First I was confident that the problem was with the data I'm using as a return_value. But it doesn't matter if I take some of it off, or try to save it to variable with pickle. In the example above I'm generating the data manually with instagram library. The data is similar with the data I get from instagram.

*edit:* Turned out that there's something very odd going on in the python-instagram-ext library or in the instagram api because max_tag_id does not work with my id. So it seems the problem may not be with the test but with api.

Comment: Try @mock.patch(<path to your view>.InstagramAPI')

Comment: This app has no view

Comment: Ok. Path to the handler_intagram method

Comment: That's how it is at the moment

Comment: no, now it's 'palautebot.management.commands.palautebot.InstagramAPI' and I propose to change it to '<your_module>.<your_class>. handle_instagram.InstagramAPI'

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry. I tried it but it gives me this error `AttributeError: <function Command.handle_instagram at 0x7f2a1c33f840> does not have the attribute 'InstagramAPI'`

I guess because instagramAPI is called inside handle_instagram but the function is located elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the problem the same way I had done earlier but I found a way to go around it. So instead of mocking instagramAPI, I mock specific functions by settings side_effect for the mock.

```
   class TestPalautebotTests(TestCase):
       def mock_initialize_instagram():
            instagram_api = instagram.client.InstagramAPI(
                access_token='access_token_foo',
                client_secret='client_secret_bar'
            )
            return instagram_api

        def mock_tag_recent_media(count=60, max_tag=None, tag_name=''):
            recent_media_mock = 'instagram-data'
            next_ = None
            mock_data_from_instagram = (recent_media, next_)
            return mock_data_from_instagram

        @mock.patch('palautebot.management.commands.palautebot.Command.initialize_instagram',side_effect=mock_initialize_instagram)
        @mock.patch('palautebot.management.commands.palautebot.InstagramAPI.tag_recent_media',side_effect=mock_tag_recent_media)
        @mock.patch('palautebot.management.commands.palautebot.Command.answer_to_instagram',side_effect=return_true)
        def test_handle_instagram(
            self,
            mock_init_instagram,
            mock_tag_recent_media,
            mock_answer_to_instagram
        ):
            self.assertEqual(self.palautebot_cmd.handle_instagram(None), [True])
```